# Jenkins : Hide a default parameter, but display it X times depending on the previous parameter

Tags: jenkins, dynamic, parameters

I am creating a jenkins job but I can't find a solution to what I want to do.

There are 3 parameters that I want to display according to a previous choice. Basically, when I choose a number, I want the parameter set (which I have framed in the image) to display "number" times, or 0 times if I chose 0. I also want the description "PARAMETERS" in blue (which is a description of "number") to display "1st PARAMETERS" "2nd PARAMETERS" etc... automatically according to the number we have chosen
[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGYnY.png)

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Active Choice parameter` for this. Please have a look at [this](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/).